# How can I get my program to check if a pressed key is in a selected word

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm working on a hangman game and I'm checking to see if the letter that the user guesses by the use of key down is in the randomly chosen saying. But it either always gives me the answer of "Yes it is in the saying" or "No it is not in the saying" no matter if the letter is actually in the saying or not. Any help much appreciated. Thankyou.

Here is the code I'm working with at the moment.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function textFunction(event)
{
if (event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) 
{
    var guess = event.keyCode;
    var a = "a";
    var letterGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(sayings[randomSaying].contains(guess)){
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
    alert(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
} 
else 
{
    alert("Please type a letter");
}
});
```

And the randomly chosen saying

```
var sayings = [
    "cash on the nail",
    "charley horse",
    "double cross",
    "fit as a fiddle",
    "hands down",
    "if the cap fits",
    "mumbo jumbo",
    "see red",
    "stone the crows",
    "thick and thin",
]
sayings.toString();
var randomSaying = Math.floor(Math.random()*sayings.length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);` returns capital letter by default. As such, you'll never match.

EDIT: Clarification, the keyCodes supplied are the capitalized letter, so the String.fromCharCode will always return a capital letter by default.

Comment: Okay so any idea how I can get them to match?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();` to make them lower case. So as long as your sayings contanis just lower case, that should work. If not, make your saying all lower case before doing the contain. Google is also a good resource for figuring out simple stuffs like changing letter cases.

Comment: Yes I think that's done it! Thankyou! I've been trying this all day but without the lowercase, such an annoying little mistake.